# Changing IP address on a "shared" Wi-Fi router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ip-address

I don't really know how to word this properly since I don't know the name, so, sorry for the odd question.

In my situation, I lived on an apartment and they provide internet service on a monthly fee through Wi-Fi. Each floor seems to have its own Wi-Fi network.

They didn't provide me the router, so the Wi-Fi network is actually publicly connectable but is blocked with a login page. (Like a cafe hotspot)

So I wanted to change my IP address, but the methods I found through google aren't working. So can anyone provide me with a solution? I am using Windows 8.1 by the way.

Comment: Most likely the router is providing DHCP, so it is assigning IPs. If you had the default gateway and subnet mask (which you can see with ipconfig), you can choose any IP within that subnet (anything outside of that subnet will not work). Understand though, that because it is DHCP, the router can hand that address to anyone else and you will have an IP conflict and connectivity problems.

Comment: Why do you want to change your IP address ? (I ask for technical reasons - is there an internal conflict or are you trying to change the external interface etc. Depending on your response the answer varies between "Get an AP Client to Get a VPN !!!"

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). There is something you want to accomplish, and you think that changing your IP address will do it. So you ask for help changing your IP address. But most likely, changing your IP address won't do whatever it is you're trying to do. Ask a question about your **problem**, not your proposed solution.

Comment: Well, it's kind of a "want to make a new certain account and start all over again and not repeating the same mistakes" kind of thing. Will using VPN be enough?

Answer (score 0):

The methods you may find discussed for changing your IP address will almost invariably
assume you have access and control of the router. As an apt renter using a shared network,
that is unlikely to be the case. You need to contact your apt network management people.
It may or may not be possible for you to secure a new IP address.

Comment: He didn't ask how to change anyone else's IP address. He asked how to change *his* IP address. He doesn't need control over the router to change his own IP address unless it uses some kind of unusual port or MAC security scheme.